# Xamarin installation failed in MAC OS X

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am facing problem to instal Xamarin in my Mac machine. It's giving problem in monotouch framework installation.

I have down loaded from http://xamarin.com  and 
down loaded file name is : XamarinInstaller.dmg

My Mac book specifications : lion 10.8.2

Please help me out..

I am getting below error.

Mono Framework installation failed with more than one exception (Attempt #Mono Framework)
Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Message: Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Failed to attach DMG image '/Users/abcd.is/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.12.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg'. Error code 1.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.MacInstallationArchiveHandler.MountDmg (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.MacInstallationArchiveHandler.InstallDmg (System.String path, Boolean needsPrivileges) [0x00000] in :0
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.InstallationArchiveHandler.Install (System.String path, Boolean needsPrivileges) [0x00000] in :0
Exception type: Xamarin.Web.Installer.InstallException
Message: Failed to attach DMG image '/Users/abcd.is/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.12.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg'. Error code 1.

Comment: Does the file `/Users/raju.istalla/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.12.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg` exist on your machine?

Comment: yes, it's in my machine..when initiates installation immediately same path was created.

Comment: What happens if you try to open that dmg? Does it install successfully?

Comment: Hi @RolfBjarneKvinge i am following below link. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac till step-1 is fine, step-2 has giving failed message.

Comment: Can you try to open a terminal and execute this: `open /Users/raju.istalla/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/Universal/downloads/MonoFra‌​mework-MDK-2.10.12.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg` (all in one line) and then see what happens?

Comment: No such file or directory. But still the file is there it's giving the same result..@RolfBjarneKvinge

Answer (score 1):

Actually, restarting the installer worked for me.